# NDSolve fails while solving PDE with Dancwerts BC

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

*The following code runs with BC1 (Dirichlet Type). However, it fails for Dancwerts type BC1.*

```
Remove["Global`*"]
\[Rho]b = 651.52; \[Epsilon] = 0.59; Dia = 0.025; u = (.5*10^-6/60)/(Pi/4*Dia^2); L = 0.15; 
kc = 0.3217*10^-4; DL = 4.0259*10^-6; KL = .078; qm = 9*10^-3; C0 = 100*10^-6/10^-3;

Eq1 = D[Conc[t, z], t] + u* D[Conc[t, z], z] - DL* D[Conc[t, z], z, z] + (\[Rho]b/\[Epsilon])D[q[t, z], t] == 0;
Eq2 = D[q[t, z], t] == kc*(Conc[t, z] - q[t, z]/(KL (qm - q[t, z])));
IC1 = Conc[0, z] == 0;
IC2 = q[0, z] == 0;
(*BC1=(Conc[t,0]-DL/u *D[Conc[t,z],z])/.z\[Rule]0.00*) (*DANCKWERTS BC1*)
BC1 = Conc[t, 0];
BC2 = D[Conc[t, z], z] /. z -> L;

Soln = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, IC1, IC2, BC1 == C0, BC2 == 0}, {Conc, q}, {t, 0, 10000}, {z, 0, L},Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {BC1 == C0}}, Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}] 

Plot3D[Evaluate[Conc[t, z] /. Soln], {t, 0, 10000}, {z, 0.00, L}, PlotRange -> All] 
Plot[Evaluate[Conc[t, L] /. Soln], {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> {0, C0}] 
Table[Flatten[{t, Evaluate[Conc[t, L] /. Soln]}], {t, 0, 10000, 500}] // TableForm
```

Comment: You specify: Conc[0, z] == 0; and Conc[t, 0]== C0 what is not consistent at {x,y}=={0,0}

Comment: Yes, You are right: NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. However, NDSolve still yields answer but with BC1 = Conc[t, 0] and it fails with Danckwerts BC1, i.e. BC1=(Conc[t,0]-DL/u *D[Conc[t,z],z])/.z\[Rule]0.00. The main problem is Danckwerts BC1 and not the inconsistent IC/BC.

Comment: You should upload a picture of the result for `BC1=Conc[t,0]` vs when `BC1=danckwertz...` to emphasize the desired result (certainly not identically 0).  Also, I don't know BC specifications very well, but is it possible to solve an ODE to specify `Conc` in full a t=0?

Comment: @user85941 This problem can be solved with using Mathematica FEM. See Help, ref/NeumannValue, Robin boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved with using Mathematica FEM. Let put `u = -(.5*10^-6/60)/(Pi/4*Dia^2);` and define  `Eq1` in accordance with Mathematica FEM as follows

```
Eq1 = D[Conc[t, z], t] - u*D[Conc[t, z], z] - 
   DL*D[Conc[t, z], z, z] + (\[Rho]b/\[Epsilon]) D[q[t, z], t];
```

Then Dancwerts type `BC1` is

```
BC1 = (-u Conc[t, z] - DL*D[Conc[t, z], z]) /. z -> 0.00
```

`BC1` in FEM notation equals to `BC1 = NeumannValue[-u (C0 - Conc[t, z]), z == 0]`. From the other side `BC2 = D[Conc[t, z], z] /. z -> L` equals to `BC2 = NeumannValue[0, z == L]`. Therefore, code in FEM notation can be written as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
\[Rho]b = 651.52; \[Epsilon] = 0.59; Dia = 0.025; u = -(.5*10^-6/
      60)/(Pi/4*Dia^2); L = 0.15;
kc = 0.3217*10^-4; DL = 4.0259*10^-6; KL = .078; qm = 9*10^-3; C0 = 
 100*10^-6/10^-3;

Eq1 = D[Conc[t, z], t] - u*D[Conc[t, z], z] - 
   DL*D[Conc[t, z], z, z] + (\[Rho]b/\[Epsilon]) D[q[t, z], t];
Eq2 = D[q[t, z], t] == kc*(Conc[t, z] - q[t, z]/(KL (qm - q[t, z])));
IC1 = Conc[0, z] == 0;
IC2 = q[0, z] == 0;
(*BC1=Conc[t,0];*)
BC1 = NeumannValue[-u (C0 - Conc[t, z]), 
  z == 0];(*DANCKWERTS \
BC1=(Conc[t,0]-DL/u*D[Conc[t,z],z])/.z\[Rule]0.00*)

Soln = NDSolve[{Eq1 == BC1, Eq2, IC1, IC2}, {Conc, q}, {t, 0, 
   10000}, {z, 0, L}];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[Evaluate[Conc[t, z] /. Soln], {t, 0, 10000}, {z, 0.00, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White],
 Plot[Evaluate[{Conc[t, L], Conc[t, 0]} /. Soln], {t, 0, 10000}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, C0}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[Conc[t, z] /. Soln, {t, 1000, 10000, 1000}]], {z,
    0, L}, PlotRange -> {0, C0}, AxesLabel -> Automatic],
 Table[Flatten[{t, Evaluate[Conc[t, 0] /. Soln]}], {t, 0, 10000, 
    500}] // TableForm}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note, that this solution computed on the mesh with 20 elements only,

```
Conc["ElementMesh"] /. Soln

Out[]= {NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh[{{0., 
    0.15}}, {NDSolve`FEM`LineElement["<" 20 ">"]}]}
```

Boundary conditions at `z=0`and `z=L`

```
{Show[Plot[(-u Conc[t, 0] - DL Derivative[0, 1][Conc][t, 0]) /. 
    Soln, {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[Table[{t, -u C0}, {t, 1000, 10000, 1000}], 
   PlotStyle -> Red]], 
 Plot[Derivative[0, 1][Conc][t, L] /. Soln, {t, 0, 10000}, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

We can also compute solution with `DirichletCondition[]` as follows

```
BC1 = Conc[t, 0];
BC2 = D[Conc[t, z], z] /. z -> L;

Sol0 = NDSolve[{Eq1 == 0, Eq2, IC1, IC2, 
    DirichletCondition[Conc[t, z] == C0, z == 0]}, {Conc, q}, {t, 0, 
    10000}, {z, 0, L}];


{Plot3D[Evaluate[Conc[t, z] /. Sol0], {t, 0, 10000}, {z, 0.00, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[{Conc[t, L], Conc[t, 0]} /. Sol0], {t, 0, 10000}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, C0}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[Derivative[0, 1][Conc][t, L] /. Sol0, {t, 0, 10000}],
 Table[Flatten[{t, Evaluate[Conc[t, L] /. Sol0]}], {t, 0, 10000, 
    500}] // TableForm}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alex for your excellent code no. 2 for Dirichlet BC. I pasted it and it ran successfully, matching with my previous code for same Dirichlet BC (same numerical values, curves etc). Albeit your code was SMARTER!!! Also, I learnt something about FEM.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alex for your Excellent code no. 2 for Dirichlet BC. I pasted and run successfully (matching with my previous results for Dirichlet BC i.e. same values, 2D/3D curves etc). Albeit your code was SMARTER one!!! Also, I learnt a new part ie MathematicaFEM. However, when i pasted your code no. 1 for Neumann BC (actually an intelligent way of Danckwerts BC1), I am getting two errors: (1) NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions .... Artificial boundary effects ..... (2) NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. Plz help...

Comment: Thanks Mr Alex. got my answer! actually we dont have to use IC2 in your code. BTW thanks again. Will ask u more about similar problems. also, pl tell a book good and easy one for getting used to apply FEM/FDM/FVM in Mathematica....a Good one and and EASY one. REGARDS.

Comment: @user85941 First, see tutorial/NDSolveOverview  about numerical methods to solve PDE implemented in Mathematica. There are nice explanation about FEM application on FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview ,   See also second popular method tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines. On this Forum we have very nice collection with FEM and FDM numerical examples. See also some topics about numerical methods on https://community.wolfram.com/dashboard